# Is there a way to register an application on Google+ like on Facebook?

Tags: google-plus, access-token, facebook-access-token

In particular I'm interested in the possibility of getting an **App Access Token**  with no expiration time, exactly as I do with Facebook.

I want to publish on behalf of the user via server, and I found very useful and convenient the Facebook's procedure in which we ask for the user permissions only the first time.

I have been working with this kind of social-networks interaction for merely three weeks, so I will be very happy to hear any type of suggestions or critics.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#about

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google+ does not currently have a public write API. There are selected partners that they work with (such as HootSuite) that provide this feature, but they are making access to it available very slowly. See https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup for further details.

Google+ does have a concept of Moments, which are activities that happen in your app that are reported to Google+ and which the user may later wish to share, or may make available to people in their circles on a limited non-notification basis. This is probably not what you want, but may serve some needs. See https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments for more info and examples how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, No there is no way to do that in Google+ in current time. In general, apps for Google plus is read only.